# Boolean value not being passed with jQuery/ $.get - Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, boolean

I have my front end script which has the following jQuery code:

```
$.get("/backend/post.php", { 
            title: title,
            message: post,
            stick: sticky
        }, function (output) {
            alert("Call Back");
            }
        }, "json");
```

stick is a boolean value, the other two are strings.  I've confirmed that they are in fact set.  Now on the backend page, using $_GET, title and, message and being passed, but $_GET['stick'] is returning empty, and the PHP function gettype() is telling me it is NULL.

**In request to one of the comments:**

sticky comes from a form, it's a check box and I just select it with this code:

```
var sticky = $("input[name=sticky]").attr('checked');
```

When I use alert() to output the value of sticky, it will return true/false depending on what was selected.

Why is this boolean value not being passed?  The JSON site tells me you can have the boolean values true/false in it.  But it is not working here for some reason.

Comment: You need to post where `sticky` comes from :)

Comment: A boolean value of `false` is likely to translate to `null` here.

Comment: @Pekka - Not null. Not even get passed back to server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't be entirely sure because I haven't tested it myself, but I think this is related to how GET requests transfer as strings. Try something like this:

```
var sticky = $("input[name=sticky]").attr('checked')?"true":"false";

$.get("/backend/post.php", { 
    title: title,
    message: post,
    stick: sticky
}, function (output) {
        alert("Call Back");
    }
}, "json");
```

It's entirely likely that this won't work, but give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

If in a form an input does not have a value it will not be sent as a parameter. So the absence of of a `$_GET['stick']` is equivalent to the query string parameter `stick=false`. So if you must have a parameter:

```
var sticky = 'true';

if($("input[name=sticky]").not(':checked')) {
    sticky = 'false';
}
```